# JustifyTextView - выравнивание текста по обоим краям

Tags: java, android

Появилась нужда выровнять текст по обоим краям, `WebView` не подходит, хочу именно в `TextView`. Посоветуйте библиотеки какие-нибудь в которых может на ваш взгляд не все громоздко.

P.S. ставлю фото, что не путали `justify` c `center`:

[image: пример]

Слева `justify` - выравнивание по обоим краям, справа стандартное выравнивание по левому краю.

**UPD**

Пробовал эту либу:

```
compile 'com.uncopt:android.justified:1.0'
```

и дальше просто `JustifiedTextView` вместо `TextView` но данный способ сильно затармаживает приложение и оно грузится порядка 25-40 секунд.

Также смотрел на английском стеке, нашел пару способов, но там по 5-7 классов надо добавлять, для такого дела я считаю не совсем разумно столько классов добавлять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [таком же вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20578041/3100967) в английском StackOverflow советуют вот эту [библиотеку](https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android)